# Loop replace generated value with default

Tags: clojure, trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate the sine of an angle based on [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Series_definition), and I'm feeding two parameters to this function: the angle's degrees and the amount of terms to compute:

```
(defn factorial [n]
  (if (= n 1) 1
    (* n (factorial (dec n)))))

(defn sine-terms [deg terms]
  (let [pi 3.14159
        radians (* deg (/ 180 pi))]
    (loop [a 0
           sine 0]
      (if (= a terms) sine
        (let
          [current-no (+ (* 2 a) 1)
           temp
            (/
              (Math/pow radians current-no)
              (factorial current-no))]
          (recur
            (inc a)
            (if (= (mod a 2) 0)
              (+ sine temp)
              (- sine temp))))))))
```

If I run this code, with `deg` as `30` and `terms` as `10`, it outputs:

```
-2.4237952736426853E44
```

Which isn't even close to `0.5`, which is the sine to `30` degrees. If I put a print at the beginning of the outer loop to print `sine` after every iteration, it outputs this:

```
0
1718.8748372639334
-8.46409695587649E8
1.250365792948E14
-8.7957538602188431E18
3.609314026964587E23
-9.694265426923215E27
1.835997368923122E32
-2.583053077880347E36
2.8057167260702447E40
-2.4237952736426853E44
```

The output gets smaller and smaller each time: I'm pretty sure that the loop is throwing away the `sine` generated, and replacing it with `0`, for some reason. I'm not sure if this is a problem with the code itself (which I doubt) or a bug in Clojure itself.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the values are getting much *larger*, not much smaller. `2.8057167260702447E40` is 2.8 times 10^40.

The cause of this problem is fairly clear: 180/pi is much larger than the intended pi/180.

As an aside, when debugging problems in general, it is much more productive to start from the assumption that a bug in the language is what is doubtworthy, and that a bug in your own code is tremendously more likely.

Comment: Dammit, I read the output wrong, I thought it was `E-44` instead of `E44` - should I delete this question?

Comment: Regardless of how big the argument is, the series ought eventually to converge to a value in [-1, 1], since the factorial denominators eventually overwhelm the powers in the numerator. No doubt it would need a huge number of terms to do so. The result would appear to be `-0.4097717985743482`,